# determining time complexity

Tags: c++, big-o

I was reading a book which tells that the outer loops time complexity is O(n-m) whereas for inner loop the books gives explanation as

> " The inner while loop goes around at most m times, and potentially
>   far less when the pattern match fails. This, plus two other
>   statements, lies within the outer for loop. The outer loop goes around
>   at most n−m times, since no complete alignment is possible once we get
>   too far to the right of the text. The time complexity of nested loops
>   multiplies, so this gives a worst-case running time of O((n − m)(m +
>   2)). "

I didn't understand for what reason the time complexity of inner loop is O(m+2) instead of O(m)? Please help.

```c
int findmatch(char *p, char *t)
{
    int i,j; /* counters */
    int m, n; /* string lengths */
    m = strlen(p);
    n = strlen(t);

    for (i=0; i<=(n-m); i=i+1) {
        j=0;
        while ((j<m) && (t[i+j]==p[j]))
            j = j+1;
        if (j == m) return(i);
    }

    return(-1);
}
```

Comment: Why was this tagged C++? Are we sure this code is C++ (could be C). The homework tag (that we're not supposed to use) might actually be better....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop:

```
    while ((j<m) && (t[i+j]==p[j]))
        j = j+1;
```

is O(m), then you have +2 from (`other statements`):

```
    j=0;                     // + 1
    // loop
    if (j == m) return(i);   // + 1
```

Comment: then why we have not given O(1) for j = 0 in outer loop, or is it we don't say O(1) to initialization statements ?by the way thanks for the response.